# How to resolve overlapping scatter points in a highchart

Tags: data-visualization, highcharts, scatter-plot

I have a time series data being plotted with Highstock API, as a scatter. When I am plotting it for a period of 5 days or more... my scatter points generated in very close proximity are getting totally overlapped. I have to close in my time frame to see that there are actually two points close by(which were overlapping).

so please help me on how i can improve display on this issue.

Comment: You can change the size of the points... Have you already tried that??

Comment: yes  i tried that. thing is the problem is not totally solved when i am considering a larger time frame, and i cannot reduce the size beyond a extent because of visibility issues

Comment: if that is the case, there isn't anything you can do to solve it... that is the nature of your chart and data. just allow the chart to be zoomable so the user can zoom in.

Comment: @petarap, I'm having the same issue, have you been able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read and observed, this is one of the reasons to use a scatter plot: to see where data sets overlap, group together, and to show possible correlation (see the formal definition over at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scatter_plot).

You may wish to add a note to the chart that encourages your users to zoom in to see more detail. The zoom function is a native part of Highcharts/Highstock, but isn't immediately obvious to many users.

It's worth noting that you can limit the zoom to either one axis (`zoomType: 'x'`) or both axes (`zoomType: 'xy'`); see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.zoomType. That may offer you a bit more control over how you want your users to view the parts of the chart with a larger number of overlapping points.